# SSRS report export to PDF, EXCEL and MS-Word format issue

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008

my report has no header and footer. my report shows show data according to country wise means grouping done on country code. i set a page break at end on the group as a result each group data is coming in new page. everything is working fine the problem is

when i click on export to pdf button on toolbar then data export to pdf but data looks very ugly when i open the pdf.
first of all there was heading at the top of report which was not at the same place when i open the pdf...header shows very below. the reason i just do not understand. lots of black space shown in report in pdf file but when report render in webpage then it looks ok. the main things is the way report render and shown in web page the same way data is not shown in pdf after exporting. why it occur i just could not figure it....so guide me what i need to do extra things as a result data should looks same in web page and in pdf file.

when i export data to ms-word format then file was created but could not open.

when i export data to excel then excel file shown data fine but all groups comes in different sheet and another problem i see that some time big text truncated.

so these are the problem i faced after exporting report to various type of file format. please anyone who faced this problem and solved it share the info with me. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing some of your layout issues are because you have overlapping objects which will render differently depending on how you export them. I would try removing any overlapping objects / rectangles and seeing if that clears up your rendering issues.